# Задача на нахождение счастливого числа

Tags: python

Есть такая [задача](https://leetcode.com/problems/happy-number/)

Я решил, но только наполовину, то есть мне нужно как-то рекурсивно запускать `for` чтобы он продолжал суммировать квадраты цифр пока не упрется в условие что сумма равна `1`, но он только один раз делает и все, поэтому не работает как нужно. Подскажите как это реализовать. Спасибо.

```
class Solution(object):
def isHappy(self, n):
    store = set()
    sum = 0
    n = str(n)

    while n > 1:
        for digit in n:
            digit = int(digit)
            sum += pow(digit,2)
        if sum in store:
            return isHappy(n)
        else:
            return
```

Comment: Нужно добавить цикл с условием, когда он должен _рекурсивно запускать for_. И подумать над условием, когда он попадает в бесконечный цикл и не попадает в 1.

Comment: @mironovmeow  а как? Можете подсказать?

Comment: Для рекурсивного решения можно создать отдельную функцию, которая будет вызывать саму себя до тех пор, пока не будет достигнуто условие счастливого числа или пока не обнаружится цикл. подсказка: сумма квадратов цифр равна 1. счастливым числом называется натуральное число, сумма квадратов цифр которого в итоге равна 1

Comment: @SeniorPomidor об этом тоже думал, но на литкод не берет такое решени

Comment: @juicy какое "такое"?

Comment: @Эникейщик то, которые написал. ошибку дает `NameError: global name 'isHappy' is not defined`

Comment: ну так не берет не "такое" решение, а потому что ошибка в коде. Неужели непонятно?

Comment: @Эникейщик понятно все, поэтому и обратился сюда, чтбоы подсказали где ошибка и что не так делаю вооьще-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не обязательно использовать рекурсию, можно в цикле заменять n на полученную сумму. Для выявления цикла используем множество.

Accepted на leetcode:

```
class Solution:
    def isHappy(self, n: int) -> bool:
        store = set()
        while n > 1:
            sm = 0
            sn = n
            while sn:
                digit = sn % 10
                sm +=digit * digit
                sn //= 10
            if sm in store:
                return False
            elif sm > 1:
                store.add(sm)
            n = sm
        return True

 >>> 12 False
 >>> 13 True
```

Вот с рекурсией, Accepted

```
class Solution:
    def isHappy(self, n: int) -> bool:
        store = set()
        def ish(n: int) -> bool:    
            sm = 0
            sn = str(n)
            for digit in sn:
                digit = int(digit)
                sm += digit * digit
            if sm == 1:
                return True    
            if sm in store:
                return False
            else:
                store.add(sm)
                return ish(sm)
        return ish(n)
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Можете мой пример дополнить рекурсией пожалуйста

Comment: Добавьте set в класс, делайте его пустым при первом вызове, делайте `return isHappy(sum)`, возвращайте False, если аргумент уже в set

Comment: обновил код, но что-то не так. `NameError: global name 'isHappy' is not defined` такую ошибку дает

Comment: Для ваших целей нужно добавить self

Comment: Однако я не знаю, насколько можно на leeetcode модифицировать класс - store должно быть полем класса. Или передаваться в happy - а это явно нельзя делать

Comment: Я исправил ошибку форматирования. На leetcode Accepted

Comment: то что вы написали и в первый раз запустилось,  я просто не понял это решение, хотел на своем поробовать, но мое ршибку дает теперь другую `Output: false Expected: true`

Comment: Запустилось, но с ошибками считало. С рекурсией будет превышение лимита рекурсии

Comment: да, у меня тоже в начале дал Time limited excedeed

Comment: Это другое......

Comment: но я все равно так и не понял как мой код можно улучшить, не хотел ваш просто копировать

Comment: хочу понять как сделать так чтобы мой проверял пока не уткнется в условие, ведь он только один раз проверяет

Comment: Исправил рекурсивный код, LC принял

Comment: я имел ввиду мой код исправить, который в описании вопроса наверху, но окей. отправил, принял. Спасибо вам.

Comment: там проблема со store, который не должен быть локальный